# Compiler Error With Binary Tree Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to write these functions for an assignment and I can't figure out where these errors are coming from or what they mean. I have 2 classes, one for the node and one for the binary tree. I recently added some functions and their implementations in my main function, and they're causing problems (mainly the public functions that call the private ones, I think). If the function declarations look weird, I apologize, they were written by my instructor so I can't really change them. Here's the functions I'm working with (I've cut out what isn't relevant or new):

```
template < class T > class binTree {
public:
binTree ( ) { // default constructor
    root = NULL;
}
binTree ( const binTree<T>& Right ) {   // Copy Constructor
    root = copy(Right.root);
}
virtual ~binTree () {   // Destructor
    clear(root);
}
binTree<T>& operator = (const binTree<T>& Right) {  // assignment operator
    if (root != NULL)
        clear(root);
    root = copy(Right.root);
    return *this;
}
void clear () {
    clear(root);
}
protected:
binTreeNode < T >* root; // root of tree
private:
void clear (binTreeNode <T>*& p) {
    if (p != NULL) {
        clear(p->left);
        clear(p->right);
        delete p;
        p = NULL;
    }
}
binTreeNode<T>* copy(const binTreeNode<T>* p) {
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        binTreeNode<T>* newNode;
        newNode = new binTreeNode<T>(*p); // modified
        newNode->left = copy(p->left);
        newNode->right = copy(p->right);
        return newNode;
    }
        return NULL; // Added 
}
```

Here's the incomprehensible garbage my compiler gives me:

```
In file included from prog7.cc:2:0:
binTree.h: In member function ‘binTreeNode<T>* binTree<T>::copy(const binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = int]’:
binTree.h:16:3:   instantiated from ‘binTree<T>::binTree(const binTree<T>&) [with T = int]’
prog7.cc:13:36:   instantiated from here
binTree.h:96:4: error: invalid conversion from ‘const binTreeNode<int>*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
binTreeNode.h:12:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘binTreeNode<T>::binTreeNode(const T&, binTreeNode<T>*, binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = int]’ [-fpermissive]
binTree.h: In member function ‘binTreeNode<T>* binTree<T>::copy(const binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = float]’:
binTree.h:24:3:   instantiated from ‘binTree<T>& binTree<T>::operator=(const binTree<T>&) [with T = float]’
prog7.cc:29:14:   instantiated from here
binTree.h:96:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘binTreeNode<float>::binTreeNode(const binTreeNode<float>*&)’
binTree.h:96:4: note: candidates are:
binTreeNode.h:12:2: note: binTreeNode<T>::binTreeNode(const T&, binTreeNode<T>*, binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = float]
binTreeNode.h:12:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const binTreeNode<float>*’ to ‘const float&’
binTreeNode.h:8:28: note: binTreeNode<float>::binTreeNode(const binTreeNode<float>&)
binTreeNode.h:8:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const binTreeNode<float>*’ to ‘const binTreeNode<float>&’
binTree.h: In member function ‘binTreeNode<T>* binTree<T>::copy(const binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’:
binTree.h:16:3:   instantiated from ‘binTree<T>::binTree(const binTree<T>&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’
prog7.cc:39:30:   instantiated from here
binTree.h:96:4: error: no matching function for call to ‘binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >::binTreeNode(const binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >*&)’
binTree.h:96:4: note: candidates are:
binTreeNode.h:12:2: note: binTreeNode<T>::binTreeNode(const T&, binTreeNode<T>*, binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]
binTreeNode.h:12:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >*’ to ‘const std::basic_string<char>&’
binTreeNode.h:8:28: note: binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >::binTreeNode(const binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >&)
binTreeNode.h:8:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >*’ to ‘const binTreeNode<std::basic_string<char> >&’
binTree.h: In member function ‘binTreeNode<T>* binTree<T>::copy(const binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = int]’:
binTree.h:101:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
binTree.h: In member function ‘binTreeNode<T>* binTree<T>::copy(const binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = float]’:
binTree.h:101:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
binTree.h: In member function ‘binTreeNode<T>* binTree<T>::copy(const binTreeNode<T>*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]’:
binTree.h:101:2: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Can anyone see what I did wrong in these few functions? I'm completely drawing a blank.

EDIT:: Now I'm getting a segmentation fault when I call my copy constructor, but it does compile. By request, here's the code for binTreeNode, but it's only for reference, I know that it works fine.

```
#pragma once
template < class T > class binTree;
template < class T > class binTreeNode {
friend class binTree < T >;
public:
    // default constructor
    binTreeNode ( const T& newData =T( ), binTreeNode < T >* newLeft = 0, binTreeNode < T >* newRight = 0 ) {
        data = newData;
        left = newLeft;
        right = newRight;
    }
private:
    T data; // data value in node
    binTreeNode < T > *left, *right; // links to other nodes
};
```

Comment: Show us the definition of binTreeNode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least one bug here:

```
binTreeNode<T>* copy(const binTreeNode<T>* p) {
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        binTreeNode<T>* newNode;
        newNode = new binTreeNode<T>(p);
```

If you're trying to make a deep copy of `p`, you need to dereference it in the copy constructor:

```
        newNode = new binTreeNode<T>(*p);
```

Comment: This solved the compiling errors, thanks! Now I've got a segmentation fault when I call my copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to return something in case `p == NULL` in the copy method:

```
binTreeNode<T>* newNode = NULL;
if ( p != NULL ) {
    newNode = new binTreeNode<T>(p);
    newNode->left = copy(p->left);
    newNode->right = copy(p->right);
}
return newNode;
```

And in C++ it's common to use `0` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: I guess it depends on who teaches you. I was always taught to use `NULL` in C++.

Comment: Good catch, I added in a return NULL; but that didn't really get rid of any errors.

Comment: @derekwolf, maybe you could post the declaration of binTreeNode, because there could be an error when you assign the left/right nodes of newNode

Answer (score 0):

The error is always refer to binTreeNode.Why don't you show us the code about binTreeNode's definition?